# Как можно в if-операторе шаблона django использовать значение переменной, переданной из представления(view) через render-функцию?

Tags: django

Как можно в if-операторе шаблона django использовать значение переменной, переданной из представления(view) через render-функцию?

Я пробовал вот так:

views.py:

from django.shortcuts import render

def somefunction(request):
return render(request, 'sometemplate.html', context = {"somevariable" : "somevalue"})

---

sometemplate.html

{% if somevariable == "somevalue" %}

some text

{% endif %}

---

Не работает. Как сделать правильно?

Comment: почему же не сработает? именно так и работает

Comment: На самом деле там у меня была ошибка в другом. Уже разобрался.